# django and ajax dropdown based on selected dropdown

Tags: ajax, django, drop-down-menu

I am trying to do a dropdown menu based on the selected dropdown and filter these results.

Here what I  did so far:

project_dropdown_options.html:

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for sw in result %}
<option value="{{ sw.pk }}">{{ sw.pk  }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

view.py: (I checked the result I am getting values.)

```
def projects_dropdown(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id')
    print(id)
    result = list(SWTypes.objects.filter(proje=int(id)).values('swtype'))
    return render(request, 'project_dropdown_options.html', {'result': result})
```

url.py

```
path('ajax/projects-sw/', views.projects_dropdown, name='ajax_projects_dropdown'),
```

Ajax script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("#projects").change(function () {
      var url = $("#personForm").attr("projects-drop-url");  
      var id = $(this).val();  // get the selected projectID from the HTML input

      $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
        url: url,                   
        data: {
          'id': id       // add the project id to the GET parameters
        },
        success: function (data) {   
          $("#sw").html(data);  
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
```

html page where the dropdown is:

```
<select name="projects">
 {% for instance in projects%}
 <option value={{ instance.id }}>{{ instance.project_title }}</option>
 {% endfor %}</td>
  <td>
    <form method="post" id="personForm" projects-drop-url="{% url 'ajax_projects_dropdown' %}" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="sw" id="sw">
    <option value="">Switch Type</option>
  </td>
  </form>
```

I think I have error either with Ajax script or the html part where the dropdown menu is.Any idea where I am doing which error ? I am getting no error and I am getting no values at the second dropdowsn menu which is called "sw" and I am getting values of the first dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `values` method in your QuerySet and only sending `swtype` field value in context while rendering `project_dropdown_options.html`

Either remove the `values` method

```
result = SWTypes.objects.filter(proje=int(id))
```

Or add `pk` as well to `values`

```
result = SWTypes.objects.filter(proje=int(id)).values('pk', 'swtype')
```

> Also, you don't have to convert `QuerySet` to `list`, you can loop over Queryset as well in the template

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for sw in result %}
   <option value="{{ sw.pk }}">{{ sw.swtype }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**

Change your parent HTML as well, replace `name` attribute of select tag with `id`, as you have attached JQuery change event on `id` i.e **`$("#projects").change`**

```
 <td>
   <!-- add id in place of name -->
   <select id="projects">
    {% for instance in projects%}
      <option value={{ instance.id }}>{{ instance.project_title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
    <form method="post" id="personForm" projects-drop-url="{% url 'ajax_projects_dropdown' %}" novalidate>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <select name="sw" id="sw">
         <option value="">Switch Type</option>
      </select>
    </form>
 </td>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Change your ajax call, remove `data` property and append `id` to URL itself as a query parameter, and use document `on` event

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#projects', function () {
  var url = $("#personForm").attr("projects-drop-url");  
  var id = $(this).val();

  console.log("urls and project_id", url, id);

  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url + "?id="+ id,
     success: function (data) {   
        $("#sw").html(data);  
     }
  });

});
```

Comment: Hello I did as you suggested result = SWTypes.objects.filter(proje=int(id)) but nothing changed .Removed the queryset list as well no changes.   I am not getting any print of the id at the view.py.I think the problem is ajax related. def projects_dropdown(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id')

Comment: @ahmet Check my update, you need to change your parent HTML also.

Comment: I change the name into id as you stated still the same. :(

Comment: @ahmet You need to modify your ajax call as well, check the UPDATE 2 section in answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177557/discussion-between-satendra-and-ahmet).